# Incremental data load in hbase

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, timestamp, hbase, apache-pig

I'm looking for the best way to load incremental data(based on timestamp of source table) into my table. I have a source table(in hbase) where in data gets updated everyday. In the first flow, I will have to transfer the full data into my test table(in hbase). The next day , I need to transfer only the newly added records from the source table. For this I'll be using the timestamp to differentiate what needs to be transferred and what not. So which is the best way to transfer. Should I use PIG, MapReduce or Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using existing classes like [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/online-hbase-backups-with-copytable-2/)? They support incremental copy.

No need to write code.

Comment: I read about the incremental data load using copy table. but i couldn't find any example. Can you please gimme an example for incremental loading using copytable..

Comment: So the idea is you use starttime and endtime. 
1. hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=tableCopy tableOriginal --starttime=1 --endtime= 1465735288000 and then 2.  hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=tableCopy tableOriginal --starttime= 1465735288000 --endtime=1465821688000 so you need to calculate where you've finished.